# Installation of chef-client(Bootstrapping) on docker container in a VM on Azure/AWS

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, docker, chef-infra

Scenario:
Bootstrapping container to chef server in the same way as we bootstrap azure VM's.

Steps to Reproduce:
Install Chef-client using knife bootstrap
Run some recipe/role to install or configure container
Expected Result:
Installation of software such as java, python, or tools such as Jenkins, tomcat

Actual Result:
Error : SSH connection timeout when knife bootstrap command is run on Local workstation

Platform Details
Centos 7.1 (Azure VM)
Docker Container - Centos 6.4

Comment: Is there a ssh server in your container ? (And is your local workstation able to ssh to Azure in general ?)

Comment: @Tensibai I am pulling an Container from Docker registry. So not sure whether that holds ssh in that.

Comment: So how do you think you could ssh to the container to install chef if there's no ssh server listening ? (exactly the error message: connection timeout)

Comment: What I mean is: before asking about knife of any other tool, just ensure you can communicate with your machine

Comment: @Tensibai- When I am trying to fetch container details using below command I see that container is Exited.
cmd used- docker exec -it f88566c370dd /bin/bash
error observed- Error response from daemon: Container f88566c370dd is not running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not how either Docker or `knife bootstrap` works. Containers are not tiny VMs and should not be treated as such. If you want to use Chef code to *build* Docker image files, Packer can do this. Using `chef-client` inside containers at runtime for production operations is very very not recommended.

Comment: Nothing to add here except: this and nothing else